# Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types in a 1 to 0..1 relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This company makes virtual widgets
The customer purchases a certain amount of credits that can be used for widgets.
When making  a purchase an individual record is created for each credit purchased, giving us Credit records w/o an associated Widget.

The customer begins making a widget (creating a widget record), giving us a Widget w/o an associated credit record.

When the widget is complete, the final step is to use a purchased credit towards their new widget. The widget record is associated with the credit record by updating Widget_ID on the credit record.

This problem involves three tables Purchase, Credit, Widget

I can create a collection of Credits on my Widget and use an include to retrieve the credit records along with the Widget object:

```
public class Widget
{
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public string WidgetName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public  ICollection<Credit> PurchasedWithCredits {get;set;}
          
}

public class Credit
{

    [Required]
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid Purchase_ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Purchase_ID")]
    public virtual Purchase Purchase { get; set; }

    public Guid? Widget_ID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Widget_ID")]
    public virtual Widget Widget { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ConsumedDate { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{        
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}


using (EFRelationContext context = new EFRelationContext())
{
     widgets = context.Widgets
       .Include(w => w.PurchasedWithCredits)
       .Where(w => w.CreateDate < DateTime.Now)
       .ToList<Widget>();
}
```

This works without errors. However I do not want a collection of credits this is a 1 to 0 or 1 relationship, so when I change

```
Public  ICollection<Credit> PurchasedWithCredits
```

to

```
public Credit PurchasedWithCredits
```

The same .Include give an error when EF starts up

```
using (EFRelationContext context = new EFRelationContext())
{
     widgets = context.Widgets
       .Include(w => w.PurchasedWithCredit)
       .Where(w => w.CreateDate < DateTime.Now)
       .ToList<Widget>();
}
```

Message:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'EFRelation.Domain.DataObjects.Widget' and 'EFRelation.Domain.DataObjects.Credit'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.'

The difference between this and other question/solutions I've seen, is the Widget is required on the Credit record nor is a Credit required on a Widget.

Using Entity Framework 6.4.4

Sample project (apologies this is far more verbose than it needs to be):
https://bitbucket.org/davidsopkopublic/efrelation1to0/src/master/

Version using a collection:
https://bitbucket.org/davidsopkopublic/efrelation1to0/src/c47e59767a7717f2b475e1ee50cbe59ad9780a52/?at=credits-collection

Comment: Put a `WidgitId` Foreign Key property on Credit, or a `CreditId` foreign key property on Widgit.  Or use the fluent configuration to specify the principal end of the relationship.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Sorry I forgot to include the Credit class. Yes there already is a foreign key property.

Comment: What version of EF?  Ther's nothing in your current model that prevents two Credits from having the same WidgitID, which would be a 1-many relationship.

Comment: Entity Framework 6.4.4

Comment: In EF 6 a 1-1 relationship must use the primary key of the dependent entity as the foreign key property, as EF 6 does not support alternate keys.  You might be better off just leaving it as a 1-many relationship.